# Custom CSS Style for Magnolia Main Sub App

Tags: magnolia

I want to add a custom css style and set my component to having this style but then I can't make it work. I tried to copy how the Jcr browser app do the custom CSS style by having a css in folder VAADIN but that one doesnt work. I also tried the App Theme but also doesn't work. I don't know what configuration I am missing. I can't seem to find a clear documentation on how to have a custom CSS for my APP.

What I just want to do is to customize my main app to display a text with a style that I can configure in a css file.

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!

[UPDATE]
I still can't make this work. But I can see that there's "app-orange" appeared in my div just like what the docs said. I just really don't know what I'm missing here, how come the CSS still doesn't work. :(

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to make this work by adding @StyleSheet({"vaadin://themes/orange/styles.css"}) in my java code.  By adding this, the styles.css is being recognized by Magnolia and all the styles there is reflected in my app. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was asked in our community forums and answered in depth as well.

https://forums.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=4d78fdd4-ad02-4b55-b1f2-ef947a888fcb

I believe that answer should be sufficient in this case.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi! Yes I saw this already and followed the instructions but I still not able to make it work. Or is it because I only have .css? Is the .scss required ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, if i put a "theme" to my app descriptor, then it will automatically look for "src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/orange/styles.css" in case my "theme" is set to "orange".  So I already followed this one, but it seems that when i inspect my main sub app, it's still using the styles.css from the admincentral and not from the orange/styles.css.. I'm really lost on how to do this one..

Comment: @5472161 -> This approach wouldn't not be replacing the admincentral css, instead it would be creating a new one.

Comment: I see, however, it seems that magnolia is not able to create my css style because when I use the dev tools, the styles.css that I'm expecting is not there. So I'm not sure if I am missing some configuration because I already followed the instruction to put a styles.css under src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/orange folder just like the sample one.  The div of my app has "app-orange" though, but the styles is missing.

Comment: any idea why Magnolia seems not able to read my custom css style... I still can't figure out why :(

Comment: can you help me with this? Thanks!